# Android set Layout

Tags: android-layout

```
     ...
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
    ...
```

I set like above layout. and the second layout height should be left over height on the screen. But if the image is big then the top linerlayout push down the bottom linerlayout. So I can not see the bottom TextView on screen.

How can I set that when load image, resize the image to fix into only parent LinerLayout?

Comment: Hope to have screen shot also

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dip"` for both layout.

So layout is divide **50%,50%.**

Comment: I don't want to 50:50, I want to Max(Leftover) height : 30 dip. do you know how to do this?